# HTML always loaded from cache

Tags: html, caching

I have a index file under www/ and apache config set DirectoryIndex to that index.html

If I use this link

```
example.com/
```

Everything works fine since the html itself has meta tag to not use cache
but if I use

```
example.com (Which in url bar will redirect to example.com/)
//Note: In chrome, the initiator for this also change to example.com
```

The index is always fetched from cache

And the second way is how normal end user type in the address. Can you guys explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

`example.com/` is treated differently than `example.com`. The slash indicates that a URL is a folder and not a document. Adding extra slashes (such as `example.com///`) will also consititute an independent caching in this regard.

I would recommend **forcing** a single trailing slash, which can be done with the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Assuming you're running at domain root.  Change to working directory if needed.
RewriteBase /

# www check
# If you're running in a subdirectory, then you'll need to add that in
# to the redirected url (http://www.example.com/subdirectory/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Trailing slash check

# Don't fix direct file links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# Finally, forward everything to your front-controller (index.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

More information regarding this can be found **[here](https://moz.com/community/q/trailing-slash-at-end-of-url)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: While you are correct, how would it explain that example.com would always get from cache ? Or that is the default behavior with DirectoryIndex?

Comment: The pages are different, and **each one** will be cached. Visiting `example.com` will cache `example.com`. Visiting `example.com///` will cache `example.com///`. The contents will be identical, but they will be cached independently. Adding slashes like this is actually a useful way to (essentially) ensure you clear your cache for testing things like CSS changes.